# How to identify the button WebElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click this button. but I can not find any web element so that the driver can find out. Help me to fix this.

```
<button type="submit" class="signupbtn btn_full btn btn-action btn-block btn-lg">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. what do you mean by **'this'** button. Please add more description to your question. And also go through the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section on [how to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you possibly add some HTML so we could try to support you in finding an appropriate selector? I'd like to help you sonce I find selector theory an important disciplin of our craft sadly often neglected but with the given Information neither I nor anyone else could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a web element in itself, write xpath for this button element and perform your action:

```
webElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
submitBtn.click();
```

To know more about 'how to create xpath'  watch this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67bzMdbhIuw